# Project array content with mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, coordinates, geospatial

My problem is that when I'm using MongoDB 2D index for coordinates everything works just fine but the JSON output is not what I desire.

```
    var schema=new Schema({
        location:{
            type:[Number],  // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
            index:'2d',
            required:false
        }
    });

    **desired output**

    {
        "_id":"xxx",
        "longitude":18.056974411010742,
        "latitude":54.31120601701069,
    }

    **what i get**

    {
        "_id":"xxx",
        "location":[18.056974411010742,54.31120601701069]
    }


    **What i tried to do**
    db.foo.aggregate(
        {$project:{
        _id:1,
        longitude:"$location.0",
        latitude:"$location.1"
    }});
```

But obviously it does not work. I hope I explained the problem good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do an [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator on the Location array first in your aggregation pipeline, then [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) the resulting documents to apply the accumulator expressions [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) and [**`$last`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/#grp._S_last).

Your aggregation pipeline should look like this (untested):

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$location" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "longitude": { "$first": "$location" },
            "latitude": { "$last": "$location" }
        }
    }
]);
```